# Is it possible to dynamically add bootstrap panels to a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap panel on a form and want to dynamically add panels.

Here is my HTML

```
<form id="subform" name="subform">
<div class="form-row"><div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<input type="hidden" id="invid" name="invid" value="4087">
                                        Month 1  
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am using the following to attempt to append to the form, but it adds a few row each time, is it possible to add a panel to the existing row?

```
$("#subform").append("<div class='col-lg-3'><div class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'><input type='hidden' id='invid' name='invid' value='4087'>Month 2</div><div class='panel-body'></div></div></div>");
```

Comment: Please post the complete javascript script you are using

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to have columns of panels rather than rows with panels, right? I assume it's due to the large column definition that you use. I would recommend exchanging `.col-lg-3` with `.col-xs-6`. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/9qLf0grz/)

Comment: You will also need to append to `.form-row` rather than `#subform`.